# merge thousand of csv files using pandas

Tags: python, loops, csv, merge

I try to combines multiple csv files into one with like columns not duplicated.

For example:
1file.csv

```
date           val      
2019-05-07     10.2
2019-05-06     10.1
2019-05-05     10.1
2019-05-04     10.0
2019-05-03     9.8
2019-05-02     10.1
```

2file.csv

```
date           val      
2019-05-07     3.2
2019-05-06     3.1
2019-05-04     3.24
2019-05-02     3.5
```

3file.csv

```
date           val      
2019-05-06     5.1
2019-05-05     5.12
2019-05-03     5.83
2019-05-02     5.15
```

merge.csv

```
date           val1   val2  val3
2019-05-07     10.2   3.2   null
2019-05-06     10.1   3.1   5.1
2019-05-05     10.1   null  5.12
2019-05-04     10.0   3.24  null
2019-05-03     9.8    null  5.83
2019-05-02     10.1   3.5   5.15
```

and the final result that I expect is like this.

result.csv

```
date           val1   val2  val3
2019-05-06     10.1   3.1   5.1
2019-05-02     10.1   3.5   5.15
```

I want something like this could anyone can help me please.

this some code that I try to loop all csv file but I don't know how to merge all of them into one file.

```py
file_path = '/Users/Desktop/P/*.csv'
for filename in glob(file_path):

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, sep=',', parse_dates= ["date"], encoding='utf-8',usecols= ['date', 'val'])
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

On way is to merge all the dataframe with `outer` method e.g. keeps all data from both data set. At the end, you have the same dataset as the one you provided 'merge.csv'.

One you have this dataset, you can filter row with these having no empty values:

Assuming you have these dataset:

```
print(df1)
#          date   val
# 0  2019-05-07  10.2
# 1  2019-05-06  10.1
# 2  2019-05-05  10.1
# 3  2019-05-04  10.0
# 4  2019-05-03   9.8
# 5  2019-05-02  10.1
print(df2)
#          date   val
# 0  2019-05-07   3.2
# 1  2019-05-06   3.1
# 2  2019-05-04  3.24
# 3  2019-05-02   3.5
print(df3)
#          date   val
# 0  2019-05-06   5.1
# 1  2019-05-05  5.12
# 2  2019-05-03  5.83
# 3  2019-05-02  5.15
```

You can merge them:

```
output_df = df1
output_df = output_df.merge(df2, on="date", how="outer", suffixes=["", "_2"])
output_df = output_df.merge(df3, on="date", how="outer", suffixes=["", "_3"])
print(output_df)
#          date   val val_2 val_3
# 0  2019-05-07  10.2   3.2   NaN
# 1  2019-05-06  10.1   3.1   5.1
# 2  2019-05-05  10.1   NaN  5.12
# 3  2019-05-04  10.0  3.24   NaN
# 4  2019-05-03   9.8   NaN  5.83
# 5  2019-05-02  10.1   3.5  5.15
```

And eventually filter row with no missing values:

```
output_df = output_df.loc[~output_df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
print(output_df)
#          date   val val_2 val_3
# 1  2019-05-06  10.1   3.1   5.1
# 5  2019-05-02  10.1   3.5  5.15
```

I let you adapt it with your for loop !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for 4 files, however if they are really thousands, then you are in a trouble.

```
import pandas as pd

merge = pd.read_csv('1file.csv', names=['date', 'val'], header=0)
for i in range(2, 5):
    filename = f'{i}file.csv'
    colname = f'val{i}'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['date', colname], header=0)
    merge = pd.merge(merge, df, on='date', how='outer')

print(merge.head())

#          date   val  val2  val3  val4
# 0  2019-05-07  10.2  10.2  10.2  10.2
# 1  2019-05-06  10.1  10.1  10.1  10.1
# 2  2019-05-05  10.1   NaN  10.1  10.1
# 3  2019-05-04  10.0   NaN  10.0  10.0
# 4  2019-05-03   9.8   9.8   9.8   9.8
```

and if you want only rows without `NaN` then only use `how='inner'` instead of `how='outer'`